# Angular router param replace encoded spaces with dashes

Tags: angular, url, interceptor, angular-router

I've got defined routing in my app and one of them is `'recipe-details/:name'`

```
const routes: Routes = [
...
  { path: 'recipe-details/:name', component: RecipeDetailsComponent },
...
];
```

where name is uniqe and can include spaces e.g. `name: "here is recipe name"`. Router encodes spaces and because of that my url looks like this `http://example.com/recipe-details/here%20is%20recipe%20name` 
I want to replace spaces with dashes to look like this `http://example.com/recipe-details/here-is-recipe-name`. But I don't want to change value of name param itself.

I have tried to intercept UrlSerializer. And it works when I am navigating in the app. But it is not working when entering the url directly, because param `name` has value with dashes `here-is-recipe-name` and cannot be read from database (because it doesn't exist in such form).

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializerInterceptor implements UrlSerializer {
    private defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        return this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url);
    }    
    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        return this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree).replace(/%20/g, '-');
    }
}
```

Is there intercepting a good idea? Or maybe there is other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: did you go through `decodeURIComponent(your_encoded_url)`

Comment: Yes. Main issue here I've got is that entering directly the url is not working with above solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is you have to add dashes explicitly when you navigate to the route and again remove the dashes and add spaces when the route is loaded.

In your case, do the following before navigating to the route :

```
navigateToRecipeDetails(name : String){
   //Add dashes in place of spaces
   let nameInRoute: String = name.split(' ').join('-');
   this.router.navigate(['/recipe-details/'+ nameInRoute]);
}
```

Now in your recipe details component do the following in component init:

```
ngOnInit()
    {
        const routeParams = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
        //remove the dashes and add spaces
        let name = routeParams.name.split('-').join(' ');
        //this is your original recipe name which you had passed from previous page
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I thought there is 'cleaner' way to do this.

Comment: Actually the best practice is to create slugs for such things and save those in the database. These slugs should be used for routing.